# stream difference between column A and B aggregated by column C and D

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

How can I stream into a table the following:

difference between Column A and B aggregated by column C and D.

```
+-------------+-------------------+--+-
| Column_A|Column_B |Column_C|Column_D|
+-------------+-------------------+--+-
|52       |67       |boy     |car     |
|44       |25       |girl    |bike    |
|98       |85       |boy     |car     |
|52       |41       |girl    |car     |
+-------------+-------------------+--+-
```

this is my try, but it is not working :

```
difference = streamingDataF.withColumn("Difference", expr("Column_A - Column_B")).drop("Column_A").drop("Column_B").groupBy("Column_C")
differenceStream = difference.writeStream\
  .queryName("diff_aggr")\
  .format("memory").outputMode("append")\
  .start()
```

I am getting this error: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'writeStream'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending how do you want to aggregate grouped data - you can do e.g.

Prerequisites (in case if you didn't set them already):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F 
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
```

For `sum`:

```py
difference = streamingDataF.withColumn("Difference", expr("Column_A - Column_B")).drop("Column_A").drop("Column_B").groupBy("Column_C").agg(F.sum(F.col("Difference")).alias("Difference"))
```

For `max`:

```py
difference = streamingDataF.withColumn("Difference", expr("Column_A - Column_B")).drop("Column_A").drop("Column_B").groupBy("Column_C").agg(F.max(F.col("Difference")).alias("Difference"))
```

And then:

```py
differenceStream = difference.writeStream\
  .queryName("diff_aggr")\
  .format("memory").outputMode("append")\
  .start()
```

The point is - if you do `groupBy` you need to also reduce, by aggregating. If you wanted to sort your values together instead try `df.sort(...)`

Comment: how do i aggregate by column C and D together?

Comment: You mean like: ```difference = streamingDataF.withColumn("Difference", expr("Column_A - Column_B")).drop("Column_A").drop("Column_B").groupBy("Column_C", "Column_D").agg(F.max(F.col("Difference")).alias("Difference_max"), F.min(F.col("Difference")).alias("Difference_min"))```?